# How to use jQuery to randomly toggle between classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to mouse over a box and have it change color randomly. It's successful so far when I only have to choose one class to toggle ( i.e. `$("#evtTarget").toggleClass(highlighted-2);`). However, I'm trying to choose a random class from 5 different highlight classes. That way, every time I mouse over the box I want it to pick a random different color to change to. Here's my code so far:

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#evtTarget").on("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);                
});

function highlight(evt) {
    $("#evtTarget").toggleClass(colors);        

    var number=(Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) +  1));
    var colors = "'highlighted'" + "-" + number;
}
```

**CSS**

```
.highlighted-1 {
    background-color:Blue;
}
.highlighted-2 {
    background-color:Purple;
}
.highlighted-3 {
    background-color:Green;
}
.highlighted-4 {
    background-color:Pink;
}
.highlighted-5 {
    background-color:Red;
}
.box{
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="evtTarget" class="box"><p>Random Highlight</p></div>
```

Please forgive the ignorance, I'm new here.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

As noted in the comments, you will want to remove the classes applied and wrap this entire feature inside of a function so you can call it on whatever event handler you prefer (`mouseenter`).

https://jsfiddle.net/rbyoj47j/2/

You could expand it further even if you want a TRULY random color by simply applying a HEX color picker and not using classes, but altering the style itself via javascript:

```
var $foo = $('#foo');
function getRandomColor() {
  var length = 6;
  var chars = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var hex = '#';
  while(length--) hex += chars[(Math.random() * 16) | 0];
  return hex;
}
$foo.mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', getRandomColor());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rbyoj47j/3/

---

If you're using predefined classes, and a specified amount of random classes you'd want to apply, you could use a switch case like this:

```
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
var element = $('#foo');
switch(rand){
  case 1:
    element.addClass('blue');
    break;
  case 2:
    element.addClass('pink');
    break;
  case 3:
    element.addClass('red');
    break;
  case 4:
    element.addClass('green');
    break;
  case 5:
    element.addClass('yellow');
    break;
}
```

View Here:

https://jsfiddle.net/rbyoj47j/

Comment: If you are using this method, you need to remove all the classes before running through this, otherwise you will not be able to cycle through the colors more than one time a piece

Comment: Updating for that exact reason and also including mouseenter function.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I love the complete randomization. Very simple and works great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove all the classes and add required class at this context, since toggleClass cannot be implemented here as it will toggle between 2 classes. Also increase the specificity for `div.highlight-1 ... n` classes. Because .box is having a property `background-color`.

```
$(function(){
  $("#evtTarget").on("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);                
});

function highlight() {
  var number= Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
  var colors = "highlighted-" + number;
  $(this).removeClass().addClass('box ' + colors);        
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wch61x50/)

If you want to set different colors comparing with previous color then just do a simple recursion.

```
$(function() {
  $("#evtTarget").on("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);
});

function highlight(e, $this) {
  $this = $this || $(this);
  var colors = "highlighted-" + getNumber();
  if ($this.hasClass(colors)) {
    highlight(null, $this);
    return;
  }
  $this.removeClass().addClass('box ' + colors);
}

function getNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wch61x50/5/)

Comment: One note for this, is that it can be the same color twice in a row using this. If he wants it to always change color, you'd need to compare to the current color.

Comment: @Tricky12 Addressed that issue.

Comment: This works, thanks. Any reason it might be a little slow? It doesn't change consistently, sometimes it will be stuck on a certain color for some time. I tried tripling the possible color options in case it was a randomization issue but that doesn't seem to have helped. Thanks again.

Comment: @EFH That is why i have provided the second code. Check the demo of it

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy sorry -- didn't see that at first, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You were very close.  I only made a couple of tweaks:

- `var colors = "'highlighted'" + "-" + number;` didn't need the inner quotes (apostrophes)
- `.box` needs to come before the `.highlighted` styles since it needs to be overridden by them
- I set the `class` attribute of the `div`

Here's the updated code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    $("#evtTarget").on("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);
  });

  function highlight(evt) {
    var number=(Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) +  1));
    var colors = "highlighted" + "-" + number;
    $(this).attr('class', 'box ' + colors);
  }

</script>

<style type='text/css'>

  .box {
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: gray;

  }
  .highlighted-1 {
    background-color:Blue;
  }
  .highlighted-2 {
    background-color:Purple;
  }
  .highlighted-3 {
    background-color:Green;
  }
  .highlighted-4 {
    background-color:Pink;
  }
  .highlighted-5 {
    background-color:Red;
  }
  
</style>

<div id="evtTarget" class="box"><p>Random Highlight</p></div>
```

Another approach would be something like this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    $("#evtTarget").on("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);
  });

  var colors = ['blue', 'purple', 'green', 'pink', 'red'];

  function highlight(evt) {
    var number= Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    $(this).attr('style', 'background-color:' + colors[number]);
  }

</script>

<style type='text/css'>
  .box{
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: gray;
  }
</style>

<div id="evtTarget" class="box"><p>Random Highlight</p></div>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working example:

```
function highlight(evt) {
  var index = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) +  1));
  var color = "highlighted" + "-" + index;
  $("#evtTarget").attr('class', 'box'); // this resets the class back to box
  $("#evtTarget").addClass(color);        
}

$("#evtTarget").on("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);
```

And fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/2gt9hmmd/3/

Now, for the errors.

1. CSS is case sensitive, so Red !== red.
2. .box background-color is declared after the highlights, and having the same priority, the .box style always overrides the highlights.
3. You don't need those extra arrows inside the highlight class string.
4. You don't need to wrap that first function in another one.
5. Toggle class just adds and removes the same color, it's on/off.
6. It's better to declare functions above using them, it improves readability
7. Try not to use words like number for variable names, it's much better when all variables make sense and describe what they store. It's not an error, just will make your life easier.